# Quantify the proportion of data not explained by explanatory variables in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear

Say I'm in a classic linear regression situation:

$Y = \beta_0X_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \dots + \beta_NX_N + \epsilon$

And that I know that my explanatory variables $X$ only explain some part of my regressand $Y$, what sort of metrics could I use to estimate the proportion of this unexplained part? I know about the fraction of variance unexplained (FVU) that can be calculated with the coefficient of determination, but after a quick search on the internet I get the feeling that it's not used that often?

I may be wrong but I'm looking for potential alternative ways of quantifying this unexplained proportion in my system.

Comment: $R^2$ is the "explained variance", and $1-R^2$ is the "unexplained variance", roughly speaking.

Answer (score 2):

$R^2$ is the proportion of variance explained, at least under [particular conditions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/551916/247274), which you have.

Consequently, $1-R^2$ would be the proportion of variance left unexplained. While this metric is not as common as $R^2$ (I’d never thought of it before I saw this question), it should not cause controversy.